# Do we get hats?

Tags: support

We missed the whole business of choosing whether or not we get hats this winterbash. Since the default option was to have hats, does this mean we'll get them?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, hats are opt-in unless you previously opted out. You're stuck with hats! (folks hating hats can of course click the 'I hate hats' link to get rid of them).

Answer (score 6):

I would **hat**e not to have hats... [The Winter Bash 2014 site](http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/) is currently live, featuring a countdown.

Comment: I can't however, say I know if a precedent has been set on other private beta sites.